# php json_decode not returning any results

Tags: php, json, forms

i am trying to figure out why i am not returning any data when i use json_decode. i'm trying to get values that are in a valid json file (yes, i tested it). when i try and use:

```
foreach($json['designs']['filters'] as $filters) {
    echo $filters['filterTypeName']; 
}
```

i am returning the values ... that's great, but i am trying to get down to the next level of the json file to pull just the values for each array under "values". here is the json file results from `file_get_contents('url')`:

```
{"designs":  {
    "filters"   :
        [
            {
                "filterTypeName":"Year",
                "filterProperty":"year",
                "values":
                    [
                        {
                            "name":"2018",
                            "value":"2018",
                            "sortvalue":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"2017",
                            "value":"2017",
                            "sortvalue":"2"
                        }, (etc.)

                    ]
             },
             {
                "filterTypeName":"Division",
                "filterProperty":"division",
                "values":
                    [
                        {
                            "name":"Resort-Apparel",
                            "value":"Resort-Apparel",
                            "sortvalue":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"College-Apparel",
                            "value":"College-Apparel",
                            "sortvalue":"2"
                        }, (etc.)

                    ]
             }, (etc.)
```

essentially, i have a select options on my form that checking against the values listed above to return designs that match the criteria.

how do i specifically search for all of the years in one select group, then all of the divisions in another select group and so-on?

thanks for any and all of your help!!

Comment: Don't you just need `foreach ($filters['values'] as $value) echo $value->name.$value->value.$value->sortvalue;` inside your foreach??

Comment: The title doesn't match up with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$json->designs-> filters` for accessing filters instead of `$json['designs']['filters']`

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, json_decode returns an object unless true is specified as the second parameters, so your options are either:

1. Use `$json->designs->filters`
2. or use `json_decode($json, true)`

Answer (score -1):

i used `foreach($json['designs']['filters'][0]['values'] as $name)` i forgot to specify the number of the array i was trying to access.